# How can I prevent jquery's load() function from overriding progress bar animated gif?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-load

I have a page filled with photos, each of which is wrapped in a div with `class="photo_wrap"`. Users can see a certain number of photos. If they want to see more, then they click on a 'See More Photos' button. While they are waiting for the photos to load I display a 'progress bar' gif with `id="spinner"`. Due to some issues with the masonry pluggin and loading photos, I have set masonry to 'reload' after all `img`'s have completely loaded. The problem is, this also prevents my 'progress bar' gif from animating. I thought that by writing `$('div.photo_wrap img').load(...` only the photos with `class="photo_wrap"` would be effected, but it still prevents my 'progress bar' gif from animating. Why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#spinner").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'my_script.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            var $container = $('#myPhotos');
            $container.append(data);

            $('div.photo_wrap img').load(function(){    
                $container.masonry( 'reload' );
            });

            $container.masonry( 'reload' );

            $("#spinner").hide();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: As given above, the ajax load runs as soon as the document is ready, not in response clicking on a 'See More Photos' button. Was that intended?

Comment: The above code is contained inside a named function that is called when the user clickw on 'See More Photos'.

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.photo_wrap img').load(function(){...});` will fire for *each* image when it loads. 
At least it would if the handler was in place before the onload event occurs.

In order to suppress image loading before the handler is in place, you can serve the images as follows :

```
<img src="", data-src="myImages/....jpg">
```

Thus, javascript can copy the url across from `data-src` to `src`, and there's no chance of the images' load events firing before the onload handler is attached :

```
function loadMoreImages() {
    $("#spinner").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'my_script.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            var $container = $('#myPhotos');
            $container.append(data);
            var promises = $('div.photo_wrap img').map(function() {
                var d = $.Deferred();
                $(this).attr("src", $(this).data('src'));//copy img url across
                $(this).load(d.resolve).error(d.resolve);//attach load and error handlers
                return d.promise();
            }).get();
            $.when.apply(this, promises).done(function() {
                $container.masonry('reload');
                $("#spinner").hide();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

*partially tested*

You will see that, in order to respond when *all* images have loaded, we pass an array of promises (one per img) to `jQuery.when`.

I'm not sure this will fix the problem but it's along the right lines.